# Ubuntu taking long, long time to boot to login screen under VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, login, 23.04

Recently installed Ubuntu 23.04 running under VirtualBox 7.0 on Windows 11. The time to boot to the Login screen is ~5 minutes. Seems to work fine following login.

I have also noticed the same delayed login experience on a VirtualBox machine running Ubuntu 22.04. Could it be a VirtualBox issue?

Some stats:
-4 CPUs
-Base memory 8192
-Video memory 128MB
-Graphics controller VMSVGA
-Acceleration 3D
-VirtualBox 7.0.8

Have been running this configuration (more or less) for years with various versions of Ubuntu. This is a new Windows 11 laptop (i7-11657, 16GB).

Any suggestions what might be causing this problem? Thank you.